# How do I speed up 'where MATCH AGAINST and DATETIME' search in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, indexing, full-text-search

I have a rather large database where I would like to search/filter on a MEDIUMTEXT (tags), DATETIME (created_time) and a BIT (include) column.

Let's say the database looks like this:

```
+------+-----------------------+--------------------------+---------+
|  id  |      created_time     |           tags           | include |
|(INT) |       (DATETIME)      |       (MEDIUMTEXT)       |  (BIT)  |
+------+-----------------------+--------------------------+---------+
|  1   | '2017-02-20 08:58:06' |         'client 1'       |    1    |
|  2   | '2017-03-01 18:12:00' | 'client 1 and client 2'  |    0    |
|  3   | '2017-03-02 02:52:35' | 'client 3 plus client 1' |    0    |
|  4   | '2017-03-03 12:41:58' |         'client 1'       |    1    |
|  5   | '2017-03-05 18:03:12' | 'client 2, client 3'     |    1    |
|  6   | '2017-03-06 20:25:45' | 'client 1 and client 3'  |    0    |
|  7   | '2017-03-08 22:51:22' |         'client 1'       |    1    |
+------+-----------------------+--------------------------+---------+
```

I have indexed the DATETIME and BIT columns and I have used a FULLTEXT index on the MEDIUMTEXT column.

If I run this statement:

```
select statement 1
------------------
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM database
WHERE (MATCH(tags) AGAINST('"client 1"' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
AND created_time >= '2017-03-01 12:00:00'
AND include = 0;
```

It takes 14 sec. to run and returns 6700 rows.

However, if I run:

```
select statement 2
------------------
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM database
WHERE (MATCH(tags) AGAINST('"client 1"' IN BOOLEAN MODE));
```

It takes 0,4 sec. to run and returns 145000 rows and if I run:

```
select statement 3
------------------
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM database
WHERE created_time >= '2017-03-01 12:00:00'
AND include = 0;
```

It takes 0,5 sec. to run and returns 25000 rows.

Now my question is, how do I make ‘select statement 1’ run faster? Do I need to first run ‘select statement 2’ and then run the ‘select statement 3’ on the results? If so, how? Anyone have experience with UNION and can I use it here? Or is there a way I can create a multiple-column index on INDEX and FULLTEXT?

---

Added info on the actual table (and not the example above) with special thanks to @rick-james

```
Query 1:
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE count(*)
    FROM  Twitter_tweet
    WHERE  created_time >= '2017-01-01 23:00:00'
      AND  MATCH(tags) AGAINST('\"dkpol\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
Query 2:
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE count(*)
    FROM  Twitter_tweet
    WHERE  MATCH(tags) AGAINST('\"dkpol\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
Query 3:
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE count(*)
    FROM  Twitter_tweet
    WHERE  created_time >= '2017-01-01 23:00:00';
```

EXPLAIN for the 3 queries:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type     | possible_keys                                      | key                | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra                             |
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | Twitter_tweet | fulltext | created_time_INDEX,SELECT_tags_INDEX,tags_FULLTEXT | tags_FULLTEXT      | 0       | const | 1      | 50.00    | Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking |
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+
| 2  | SIMPLE      |               |          |                                                    |                    |         |       |        |          | Select tables optimized away      |
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+
| 3  | SIMPLE      | Twitter_tweet | range    | created_time_INDEX,SELECT_tags_INDEX               | created_time_INDEX | 6       |       | 572286 | 100.00   | Using where; Using index           |
+----+-------------+---------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `Twitter_tweet` (
   `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `from_user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `from_user_username` tinytext,
   `from_user_fullname` tinytext,
   `message` mediumtext,
   `created_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `quoted_post_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `quoted_user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `quoted_user_username` tinytext,
   `quoted_user_fullname` tinytext,
   `to_post_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `to_user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `to_user_username` tinytext,
   `truncated` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `is_retweet` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
   `retweeting_post_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `retweeting_user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `retweeting_user_username` tinytext,
   `retweeting_user_fullname` tinytext,
   `tags` text,
   `mentions_user_id` text,
   `mentions_user_username` text,
   `mentions_user_fullname` text,
   `post_urls` text,
   `count_favourite` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `count_retweet` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `lang` tinytext,
   `location_longitude` float(13,10) DEFAULT NULL,
   `location_latitude` float(13,10) DEFAULT NULL,
   `place_id` tinytext,
   `place_fullname` tinytext,
   `source` tinytext,
   `fetchtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `post_id_UNIQUE` (`post_id`),
   KEY `from_user_id_INDEX` (`from_user_id`),
   KEY `quoted_user_id_INDEX` (`quoted_user_id`),
   KEY `to_user_id_INDEX` (`to_user_id`),
   KEY `retweeting_user_id_INDEX` (`retweeting_user_id`),
   KEY `created_time_INDEX` (`created_time`),
   KEY `retweeting_post_id_INDEX` (`retweeting_post_id`),
   KEY `post_all_id_INDEX` (`post_id`,`retweeting_post_id`,`to_post_id`,`quoted_post_id`),
   KEY `quoted_post_id_INDEX` (`quoted_post_id`),
   KEY `to_post_id_INDEX` (`to_post_id`),
   KEY `is_retweet_INDEX` (`is_retweet`),
   KEY `SELECT_tags_INDEX` (`created_time`,`is_retweet`,`post_id`),
   FULLTEXT KEY `tags_FULLTEXT` (`tags`),
   FULLTEXT KEY `mentions_user_id_FULLTEXT` (`mentions_user_id`),
   FULLTEXT KEY `message_FULLTEXT` (`message`),
   FULLTEXT KEY `content_select` (`tags`,`message`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: The `AND include=0` makes a big difference in performance; please be consistent between the original query and the added `EXPLAINs`.

Comment: Sorry - was just trying to simplify. But I have more or less left the include column out, in an attempt to speed up things (also it is more of a nice-to then need-to, so...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When timing, do two things:

- Turn off the Query cache (or us `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE...`)
- Run the query twice.

When a query is run, these happen:

1. Check the QC to see if *exactly* the same query was recently run; if so, return the result from that run.  This usually takes ~1ms.  (This is not what happened in the examples you gave.)
2. Perform the query.  Now there are multiple sub-cases:

   - If the "buffer pool" is 'cold', this is likely to involve lots of I/O.  I/O is slow.  This *may* explain your 14 second run.
   - If the desired data is cached in RAM, then it will run faster.  This *probably* explains why the other two runs were a lot faster.

If, after compensating from these, you still have issues, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for the cases.  (There could other factors involved.)

**Schema critique**

One way to improve performance (some) is to shrink the data.

- `lang` tinytext, -- there is a 5 char standard
- `BIGINT` takes 8 bytes. A 4-byte `INT` is enough for half the people in the world.  (But first verify that your `AUTO_INCREMENTs` are not burning a lot of ids.)
- For subtle reasons, `VARCHAR(255)` is better than `TINYTEXT`, even though they seem equivalent.  Whenever practical, use something less than 255.
- `FLOAT(13,10)` has some issues; I recommend `DECIMAL(8,6)/(9,6)` as sufficient for distinguishing two tweeters sitting next to each other (not that GPS is that precise).
- A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key; get rid of the redundant `UNIQUE`.
- With `INDEX(a, b)`, you don't also need `INDEX(a)`. (at least 2 cases of such)

**Bulk**

What will you do with 6700 or 25000 rows in the resultset?  I ask because the effort of returning lots of rows is part of the performance problem.  If your next step is to further whittle down the output, then it *may* be better to do the whittling in SQL.

**Analysis**

Looking at the second set of Queries:

1. FT + date range.  This first did the FT search, then further filtered by date.
2. FT, count results, quit.  Note that all of that was done in the `EXPLAIN`, hence "Select tables optimized away" -- and the `EXPLAIN` time is the same as the `SELECT` time.
3. Scan one index for an *estimated* 572K rows -- done entirely in the index.  This cannot be improved.  However, it can be made severely worse -- such as by adding a seemingly innocuous `AND include = 0`.  In this case it would not be able to use *just* the index, but instead would have to bounce between the index and the data -- a lot more costly.  A cure *for this case*:  `INDEX(include, created_time)`, which would run faster.

`COUNT(*)` is potentially cheap -- no need to return lots of data, often can be completed within an index, etc.

`SELECT col1, col2` is faster than `SELECT *` -- especially because of `TEXT` columns.

Comment: Afraid I'm a bit more rookie at MySQL then your answer implies - but I have made a go at it :-)

So I restarted the server and ran the queries with SQL_NO_CACHE and it gave me the same result as without SQL_NO_CACHE (within a few milliseconds). It is still rather slow (however it helped when I change the tags column from MEDIUMTEXT to TEXT).

As I have buildt the table in MySQL Workbench I don't have the CREATE TABLE command, but the EXPLAIN SELECTfor the actual table I'm using looks like this:

1 SIMPLE Twitter_tweet  ALL created_time_INDEX,SELECT_tags_INDEX    1134012 10.49 Using where

Comment: `SQL_NO_CACHE` confirms that the "Query cache" is not confusing the  timings.  The first query after restarting will be slower because nothing is in the buffer_pool (a different cache), hence my suggestion to run timings twice -- I should have said 'twice in a row'.

Comment: And... Can we see all 3 EXPLAINs.  `TEXT` vs `MEDIUMTEXT` should have mattered much.  Which Engine are you using?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks for the patience :) I have added the 3 EXPLAINs and SHOW CREATE TABLE to the question above

Comment: (Typo in my prev comment.)  `TEXT` vs `MEDIUMTEXT` should _not_ have mattered much.

Comment: (augmented my answer to address explains and create)

Comment: Thanks for you answer - I was hoping for some quick-fix to it, but seems it is a bit more complicated than that. I’ll try optimizing according to your suggestions and maybe I’ll have a look at junction table sometime in the future.